# name regex in flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am using this regex : `r"^\s*([A-Za-z]{3,}([\.,] |[-']| ))+[A-Za-z]+\.?\s*$"` in flutter dart for user name. I am trying to put name as "Hello" it gives error and if I type "Hello world" then it works fine. I want it to be work in both ways whether it is "hello" or "hello world" but must be without any numeric value in it. Pls help.

```
I want it to work in any of it:-
Hellö World
Hello ó world
hello world
Hello WORLD
hellO' World
hello
HELLO
```

Comment: What are the pattern requirements? Right now, the problem is with `+` after`))`, replace it with `*`. `^\s*(?:[A-Za-z]{3,}(?:[.,] |[-']| ))*[A-Za-z]+\.?\s*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jz2Tm6/1)).

Comment: The alternation `([\.,] |[-']| )` should match at least one alternative.

Comment: I have updated. pls check.

Comment: Like `^\s*[A-Za-z]{3}[^\n\d]+$` https://regex101.com/r/CqChfZ/1

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern does not match because:

- This part `([\.,] |[-']| )` requires at least a match from one of the alternatives
- This part `[A-Za-zöó]{3,}` matches 3 or more characters. The pattern uses that in a repeating group, so all words before the last `[A-Za-zöó]+` should have 3 or more chars.
- The pattern also does not take chars like `öó` into account, and note that `\s` can also match a newline

If you want to start the string with optional whitespace chars and at least 3 chars [A-Za-z] without matching any digits:

```
^\s*[A-Za-z]{3}[^\n\d]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `[A-Za-z]{3}` Match 3 chars A-Za-z
- `[^\n\d]*` Optionally match any char except a newline or digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wWwAfh/1)

For a more specific match, you might use `\p{L}` with unicode enabled to match any letter and use a character class `[.,']?` to optionally match any of the listed characters:

```
^\s*\p{L}{3,}(?:[.,']? \p{L}+)*\.?\s*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWd1JM/1)